# Set API MaxTimeout in Loopback.io and detect slow apis

Tags: node.js, api, loopbackjs, loopback

We are using `loopback.io` for writing and exposing our apis.

I need to do two things on my apis -

1. Need to set max timeout say 30 sec. max, for all apis. ( I tried some ways from Internet, none of them worked. )
2. If I am able to set the timeout for apis, I Need to get Slow apis list like alert, email or slack notification whatever possible.

All APIs which are not able to give response withing 29 seconds, I will send the api name as an slack notification that the API is taking time.

Any workaround on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Just an idea how to organize it... The standard "strong-error-handler" logs requests time. It's enough to determine slow requests. According to notifications, we are using logentries for these purporse (https://logentries.com). It allows to create alerts and has slack integration. Just send notification when response time more than 30 seconds. But these feature available only for paid subscriptions.